# Install F# standalone on MAC

Tags: f#

I have installed `Install the F# Cross-Platform Runtime (called Mono)` from [this instruction](http://fsharp.org/use/mac/). The installation completed without errors, but I cannot find `fsharp`:

```
  ~ » fsharpi
 zsh: command not found: fsharpi
```

How can I find the path to installed files?

Comment: Did you do this step: When you run mono, use /mono64/bin/mono and put /mono64/bin on your path. Adjust other applications that launch mono to use this location.

Comment: This step is from `Option 3: Install from source`.  I am using `Option 2`.  I don't have /mono64.

Comment: Have installed from source and problem disappeared

Answer (score 0):

Well, it looks like maybe it isn't symlinked.

Here's some notes I made going through the same attempts:

- http://compositecode.com/2015/05/07/os-x-and-f-clone-it-build-it-install-it-hack-it/
- http://compositecode.com/2015/05/15/simplifying-bash-repl-use-with-f/